How to rearrange columns in Flextable?
I am encountering the following problem: Whenever I use Flextable to display my data, the Variables column always comes on the right even though in the original dataset it is on the left.
I even tried to re-combine the columns such that in the original dataset the variables are on the right to see whether it is a glitch of Flextable, but expectedly, it is not working.
Please help me figure out how to rearrange the position the variables column such that it appears on the left.
Output of data in R console:

Output of data using Flextable:

#regular R table output

row1=c("Diabetic Individuals (N1=60)", "",  "Healthy Individuals (N2=330)", "")
row2=c("Categorical variables", "          ", "", "")
row3=c("Frequency", "Percentage", "Frequency", "Percentage")
row4=c(stats_gender_m_d, stats_gender_m_h)
row5=c(stats_gender_f_d, stats_gender_f_h)
row6=c(stats_location_B_d, stats_location_B_h)
row7=c(stats_location_L_d, stats_location_L_h)
row8=c("Continuous variables", "          ", "", "")
row9=c("Mean", "Standard Deviaiton", "Mean", "Standard Deviaiton")


table3=rbind(row2, row3, row4, row5, row6, row7, row8, row9)

rownames(table3)=c("", "", "Males", "Females", "Buckingham", "Louisa", "", "")


col2=c (round(mean (chol_d),2), round (mean (stab.glu_d),2), round (mean (hdl_d),  2), round (mean (glyhb_d),2), round (mean (ratio_d),2), round (mean (age_d),2), round (mean (height_d),2), round (mean (weight_d),2))
col3=c (round(sd (chol_d),2), round (sd (stab.glu_d),2), round (sd (hdl_d),  2), round (sd (glyhb_d),2), round (sd (ratio_d),2), round (sd (age_d),2), round (sd (height_d),2), round (sd (weight_d),2))
col4=c (round(mean (chol_h),2), round (mean (stab.glu_h),2), round (mean (hdl_h),  2), round (mean (glyhb_h),2), round (mean (ratio_h),2), round (mean (age_h),2), round (mean (height_h),2), round (mean (weight_h),2))
col5=c (round(sd (chol_h),2), round (sd (stab.glu_h),2), round (sd (hdl_h),  2), round (sd (glyhb_h),2), round (sd (ratio_h),2), round (sd (age_h),2), round (sd (height_h),2), round (sd (weight_h),2))

table4=cbind(col2, col3, col4, col5)


rownames(table4)=c ("Total Cholesterol, mg/dL (N1=60, N2=329)","Stabilized Glucose, mg/dL (N1=60, N2=330)", "High Density Lipoprotein, mg/dL (N1=60, N2=329)", "Glycosylated Hemoglobin, % (N1=60, N2=330)", "Cholesterol/HDL Ratio (N1=60, N2=329)", "Age (N1=60, N2=330)", "Height, inches (N1=59, N2=329)", "Weight, lb (N1=59, N2=330)")

table_data=rbind(table3, table4)

colnames(table_data)=row1


#using the flextable package

library(flextable)

pretty_table <- as.data.frame(table_data)
pretty_table$"Variable" <- rownames(table_data)
ft <- flextable(pretty_table)




ft <- add_header_row(ft, colwidths = c (4, 1) , values = c("   Summary Statistics on Diabetic and Healthy Individuals in Buckingham and Louisa Counties", ""))



ft<-merge_at (ft, i=1, j=1:5)
ft<-merge_at (ft, i=2, j=1:2, part = "header")
ft<-merge_at (ft, i=2, j=3:4, part = "header")
ft<-merge_at (ft, i=7, j=1:5)




ft <- theme_vanilla(ft)

ft <- add_footer_lines(ft, "   Table 1. Diabetes in Buckingham and Louisa counties. Summary statistics of key blood parameters of diabetic and healthy individuals. Out of initial 403 observations, 390 have been selected for analysis, 13 have been excluded due to insufficient data.")
ft <- color(ft, part = "footer", color = "#666666")
                     
ft<-align(ft, i= c (1, 7), align="center", part = "body")
ft<-align(ft, i=2, j=c(1,3), align="left", part = "header")


plot(ft)


Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete example of your code to illustrate the issue and a snippet of your input data shared using dput() (or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset).

Hello Stefan! Thank you, will try.

Well, the issue is simply that the Variable column is the last column of your data (you probably confused with the row names). To have Variable as the first column you can add it to pretty_table using pretty_table <- cbind(list(Variable = rownames(table_data)), pretty_table)
